# Setting name of (newly created) functions via IDAPython

Tags: ida, idapython

Is there a way to specify the name of a function when creating it with `idc.MakeFunction()`?

If not, what is the best practice to rename a function?
I found `idc.GetFunctionName(ea)` but no counterpart to set a name. A google research turned up some examples where people used `idc.MakeNameEx()`. Yet, the purpose of `MakeNameEx`seems to be to rename addresses:

```
def MakeNameEx(ea, name, flags): """ Rename an address

@param ea: linear address
@param name: new name of address. If name == "", then delete old name @param
flags: combination of SN_... constants
```

And involves a whole bunch of flags such as:

```
[...]
SN_NOCHECK    = idaapi.SN_NOCHECK    # Replace invalid chars with SubstChar
SN_PUBLIC     = idaapi.SN_PUBLIC     # if set, make name public 
SN_NON_PUBLIC = idaapi.SN_NON_PUBLIC # if set, make name non-public 
SN_WEAK       = idaapi.SN_WEAK       # if set, make name weak 
SN_NON_WEAK   = idaapi.SN_NON_WEAK   # if set, make name non-weak
[...]
```

What I need is a simple rename of a function keeping all its properties, flags etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`idc.MakeName(ea, name)` should suffice.

Note that the flags accepted by [`MakeNameEx()`](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/203.shtml) don't change the function's properties or function's flags; they're instead used with regard to how the naming itself is handled.