# How can I parse VMTs in IDA if I have the base address?

Tags: idapython, vtables

I have run the Class Informer plugin to identify virtual method tables.  I am trying to write a python script which will rename each function in the table.  I am struggling to find the correct API call to change an .rdata subroutine name.  I have read through this guide, but I'm still confused:  http://www.offensivecomputing.net/papers/IDAPythonIntro.pdf

e.g.,  if I have this vmt for ExampleClassA:

```
.rdata:004F0EE8     ??_7?$ExampleClassA@$@@@ dd offset sub_25DFAD
.rdata:004F0EE8                                             ; DATA XREF: sub_256CB0+98
.rdata:004F0EE8                                             ; CNetChan____45+86 ...
.rdata:004F0EEC                     dd offset sub_3B0760
.rdata:004F0EF0                     dd offset sub_1A2080
....
```

I want to enter the base address ( 0x004F0EE8 ) and iterate over the table to rename each subroutine based on a user-supplied name.  I can iterate, get input, move ea.

How do I modify the subroutine name of the current line?

Comment: See [Setting name of (newly created) functions via IDAPython](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9016/setting-name-of-newly-created-functions-via-idapython)

Comment: Also, Igor Skochinsky already wrote IDC scripts for that particular task (http://www.openrce.org/downloads/details/196), it could be helpful.